# Как замаскировать часть текста в unity?

Tags: unity3d, ui

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы часть текста, которая не влезает в окно, не была видна, но я не могу настроить взаимодействие с маской для текста. Я пробовал найти информацию в интернете и в документации и ничего не нашел.

[image: окно]

Answer (score 0):

Я уже сам решил эту проблему. Мне очень помогла эта статья: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/176170/how-to-use-a-sprite-mask-or-shader-to-mask-a-text
Если коротко, то надо было вместо обычного компонента text использовать TextMeshPro и использовать sprite-mask.